# CSV column head with trailing space?

Tags: powershell

I have some CSV files. The following is an example. Note that the headers of column `B Y` and `C Z` have trailing spaces.

```
A X,B Y ,C Z  ,D
1,2,3,4
....
```

The following script returns empty values for `B Y` and `C Z`.

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | select -Property "A X", "B Y", "C Z"
```

Is it a way to return the values even if there are trailing spaces in the column headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple solution but it has a caveat

```
Import-Csv c:\temp\temp.csv | select -Property "A X*", "B Y*", "C Z*"
```

Using the asterisks it matchs the column that *starts with* `C Z`. While not in this case there is however a chance to potentially match other columns as well. Like if there were two columns "C Z  " and "C Znotme" both would be returned.

**Another Idea**

If you wanted to you could fix the file by removing those outer white spaces from the columns

```
$path = "c:\temp\temp.csv"
$file = Get-Content $path
($file[0] -replace "\s*,\s*",",").Trim()  | Set-Content $path
$file | Select -Skip 1 | Add-Content $path
```

- `"\s*,\s*",","` would replace and whitespace around commas
- `.Trim()` would get any leading or trailing whitespace

Write the first line back to file and then add the remaining content. This is not ideal for files with 1000's of lines but it would still work.

Comment: No need for the asterisks. Just add the space.

Comment: @NewGuy he needs the asterisk in case the space is not there. It is not always there is the point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select them by column position:

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv | select -Property ($_.psobject.properties.name)[0,1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the space as it is seen in the CSV file.

```powershell
Import-Csv .\test.csv | select -Property "A X", "B Y ", "C Z "
```

Interesting thing about PowerShell is that it doesn't care if it's variables have spaces in the names. In this case it is all about the parser and making sure PowerShell knows what it is you are looking for.

```powershell
New-Variable -Name "Variable 1" -Value "Value 1"
Get-Variable -Name "Variable 1" # Will return "Value 1"
${Variable 1} # Will return "Value 1"

$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ "Some Property" = "Value" }
$obj.'Some Property' # Will return "Value"
```

Comment: The op says _if there are trailing spaces in the column headers_ meaning they might not be there.